# I have an error with description tag in RSS

Tags: php, rss

I have this error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 15 at column 812: Opening and ending tag mismatch: br
>   line 0 and description Below is a rendering of the page up to the
>   first error.

This error displays only when I add the (discription) tag, without it I don't have any errors and I need it, and when I look at the source code I can see the discription tag with it's content.
I have tried many ways to pass this problem, but now I'm hopeless, I'm using this class: [rss_generator.inc.php](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/13354.html)

I know that the problem is not from the class, because I have tried many classes and I have the same error.

and her it is the outpu in the browser's page source:

```
<item>
      <title>السودان.. مقتل ستة اشخاص في احتجاجات</title>
      <description>اعلنت متحدثة باسم الحكومة يوم امس، قتل ستة اشخاص خلال احتجاجات على ارتفاع اسعار وسائل النقل في اقليم دارفور في السودان.وذكر شهود عيان في وقت سابق لوكالة فرانس برس ان الشرطة اطلقت الغاز المسيل للدموع على المتظاهرين الذين كانوا موزعين في مجموعات في السوق الرئيسية.واضاف ان المتظاهرين القوا الحجارة على مبان حكومية واحرقوا اطارات في الشوارع.وقالت المتحدثة ان التظاهرة بدأت بسبب رفض الطلاب لاسعار وسائل النقل التي اعلنتها الحكومة.</description>
      <link>http://www.mysite.com</link>
      <pubDate>2012-08-01 13:08:04</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://newsite.com</guid>
    </item>
```

Any suggestions please??
sorry for my bad english

Comment: Could you show us the content of the description tag?

Comment: here it is: $item->description = $article['news']; but in the browsers page source i can see the data's that it returns. thanks

Comment: I was wondering if there were illegal characters or non-xml tags in the description, that was why I asked for the description. Look for html tags or unicode characters in the page source.

Comment: I dont think if it's the problem because i used (strip_tags) function like that: $item->description = strip_tags($article['news']); but it's the same

Comment: I think we won't be able to help unless you show us some of the xml source your code generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set the discription in `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` to avoid this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<rss version="2.0">

    <channel>

        <item>
            <description><![CDATA[ Your description ]]></description>
        </item>

    </channel>

</rss>
```

So the description can contain any html tag.

Hope this will help.